# FTP Username and password wrong while installing theme

Tags: themes, authentication, ftp

I followed [Failed to connect to FTP Server 127.0.0.1/:21](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65797/failed-to-connect-to-ftp-server-127-0-0-1-21)

And was able to solve that problem. But now when I try to upload the theme then I get username and password failure.

I have added following lines in wp-config.php

```
define( 'FS_METHOD', 'ftpext' );
define( 'FTP_BASE', '/var/www/wordpress/' );
define( 'FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/' );
define( 'FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/' );
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'FTP_SSL', false );
```

How I can resolve this problem?[image]

**UPDATE**:

I tried [this link](http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2009/03/05/how-to-setup-vsftpd-ftp-on-ubuntu-linux/) and removed all values for ftp which are in wp-config.php
But still same error.

Comment: So you want to bypass from this step?

Comment: No, I want to use the authentication but it is saying wrong authentication

Comment: Have you tried sFTP?

Comment: Can you upload the theme via FTP then just activate it in WP?

Comment: The username and password you put in are correct right? you haven't just copypasted without modification?

Answer (score 3):

if you do not want to (or you cannot) change permissions on wp-content so your web server has write permissions, then add this to your wp-config.php file:

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Don't ask FTP Hostname,username,pass. this code Direct Access.

Comment: Please [edit your answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/222576/edit). Explain what happens.

Comment: +1 Exactly what was needed. I believe this should be more secure than ftp since wp already has group privileges to edit /var/www/html (as with when you upload an image), and thus should apply to plugins and exentions (which ask for ftp by default).

Answer (score 1):

Back up the config file before making a change;

```
sudo cp /etc/vsftpd.conf /etc/vsftpd.conf.back
```

and then edit vsftpd.conf (with vi or nano)

```
nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

Then make the following change

```
pam_service_name=ftp
```

Save your change and restart the ftp server (if you use nano hit CTRL+O & enter to save then CTRL+X to exit)

```
sudo service vsftpd restart
```

Answer (score -1):

NO, this is only because of the owner/permission of your folder where wordpress files are present. Please check the folder permission, if that is 0755 then replace it with 0777 by using `chmod 777 -R FOLDERNAME` 
and try to upload, After this if will get again same issue change the folder owner by using `chown www-data FOLDERNAME`

For example in your case the folder name is **wordpress** then use the following commands for changing permisssion/owner

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I believe this will work for you.

Also you can define FS_METHOD as direct in wp-config.php so you will not get FTP detials at the time of installation of Theme/Plugin.

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct);
```

Thanks

Comment: nothing except maybe the upload directory should have a 777 permission